# Haskell ignore unresolved imports

Tags: haskell, import, template-haskell

Very specific use case: I'm building an autotester system, where students submit their assignments, which is automarked.

However, VSCode will often insert bogus imports, which cannot get resolved on the testing machine. However, those modules are never used. Is thee a way to ignore the error, and force compilation? Something like `-fdefer-out-of-scope-variables`?

This is the kind of error, can I forcefully ignore it, and throw only if a symbol cannot be resolved?:

```
Submission.hs:5:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘GHC.CmmToAsm.PPC.Instr’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. Are your studends using VSCode and submitting solutions with bad imports? If so, tell them to stop doing it if they want a grade.

Or is VSCode somehow part of your workflow when grading, and it's editing student files to have bad imports? If so, either figure out how you're misusing VSCode, or use a different tool than VSCode to compile.

Either way, trying to trick GHC into compiling invalid source files doesn't seem like the right approach.

Comment: Is what OP is asking for really any more unreasonable than `-fdefer-out-of-scope-variables` is?

Comment: They're using VSCode and submitting a bad file, but at the same time that's not what they're being assessed on, so the main problem is that if it doesn't compile, a marker has to go and fix it manually

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm looking for something exactly like that, but that also works with imports